# Assigning values to dialog box having Textbox and TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having two values .I am facing a problem in assigning these values to textfields of a dialog box using query.I am doing like this :

```
 $('.editbutton').click(function ()
        {
            var qtitle=$('#questiontitle').val();
            var qtext=$('#questiontext').val();
            $("#dialog").html("Title: <input id='myquestiontitle' type='text'><br><br>Question :  <textarea id='myquestion' type='text'>");
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                title: "Edit Your Question",
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: { 

                "Edit": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                callback("1");
            },
               "Discard": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback("2");
            }

            }

    });

  });
```

I just want that qtitle to assign to first textbox and qtext to textarea.Please help

Answer (score 0):

use

```
"Title: <input id='myquestiontitle' type='text' value='"+qtitle+"'> <br><br>Question :  <textarea id='myquestion'>"+qtext+"</textarea>"
```

**Now over all code look like below**

```
 $('.editbutton').click(function ()
        {
            var qtitle=$('#questiontitle').val();
            var qtext=$('#questiontext').val();
            $("#dialog").html("Title: <input id='myquestiontitle' type='text' value='"+qtitle+"'> <br><br>Question :  <textarea id='myquestion'>"+qtext+"</textarea>");
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                title: "Edit Your Question",
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: { 

                "Edit": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                callback("1");
            },
               "Discard": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback("2");
            }

            }

    });

  });
```